# Installing Ubuntu over Mint in a dual boot configuration

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, mint

I'm attempting to replace an existing Mint installation with Ubuntu on a UEFI system. The complication is that I'm dual-booting with Windows, and I'm very wary of messing that up in the process.

In the installer, I'm choosing to do "something else" as the installation type. I am then presented with the following (I've stitched multiple screens together to make this a bit easier to understand):

[image: partition table]

I'm unsure on exactly what I need to do here to ensure my Ubuntu replaces my Mint. I'm particularly concerned about the following:

1. Will Grub show me only Ubuntu and remove the current Mint entry?
2. The "Device for boot loader installation" has me concerned. Should I leave this as `/dev/sda`?
3. Do I need to manually delete the partitions currently used for Mint?

Can anyone tell me the exact procedure I should follow here?

Answer (score 0):

No, 
You should still use dev/sda as a hdd selector 
You should have a partition for the current computer, only that unless you back track

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer? The OP may not be helped much by this answer imho. What you say, could be a comment in stead of an answer.